# Center a div within a div and make the outter div autosize according to inner div

Tags: html, css

Right now I can either auto-size the container div to the inner div or I can center the whole thing... but I can't figure out how to do both at the same time.

Below is the CSS/Layout as I have it. Right now both the `page` and `main` elements are centered but if the content is beyond a certain size it goes over the borders without either element re-sizing.

**LAYOUT**

```
</head>
    <body>
        @using Monet.Common
        <div id="contentContainer">
            <div class="page">  
                @Html.Partial("NavBarPartial")
                <section id="main">
                    <div id="content">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer">
                        <span style="color: Gray;"> </span>
                    </div> 
                </section>
           </div>            
        </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentContainer {
    width: 100%;    
}

.page 
{
    width: 50%;  /*1030px;/*75em;/*83.7em;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content {
    padding: 20px;
}


#main 
{
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white; 
    /*border: 1px solid #999;*/
    border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);

}



footer, 
#footer 
{
    /*background-image: url('Images/TEST2body_bot.png');*/
    background-color: #fff;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem I'm having is best illustrated w/two examples. In one instance I have a table that is 1030px wide. This table is left-justified perfectly but the right edge of the table flows well beyond the right border of the `main` element.

Another problem is with a set of radio buttons. When the page loads there is supposed to be nothing but white space to the right of the buttons. A specific menu appears to the right of the radio buttons based on the user's selection. When the page loads it looks like there's *just* enough space for the menus, however they are loading UNDERNEATH the radio buttons instead of to their right.

**SECOND EDIT**

This is the CSS that allows me to auto-size the `div`, however everything is left justified (commented out certain sections and added `display: inline-block` and `overflow: auto` to `.page`).

```
/*#contentContainer { Had to comment this whole section out
    width: 100%;    
}*/

.page 
{
    /*width: 50%;  /*1030px;/*75em;/*83.7em; Needed to comment this attribute as well*/
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#main 
{
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white; 
    /*border: 1px solid #999;*/
    border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);

}
```

Comment: can you make fiddle for this .. ?

Comment: @Neha here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Ns/

Comment: umm i also made fiddle but adding dummy text on #content and #footer its stays in box.. so wondering what is that certain size which is breaking .. if u can show issue in fiddle it will be gr8.

Comment: Tell us more about your problem. Is your problem with resizing on different devices? How is the content size being changed?

Comment: ^ I second this, though I will say if you want `.main` to show around the content, set a width and height on `content`.

Comment: No, not different devices. There are two issues I'm running into: one is a table 1030px wide and another is a set of menus that are not supposed to appear until the user selects a radio button. In this instance instead of appearing to the right (if you're looking at the screen) they appear below the radio buttons. I figure if I can solve the 1030px table problem that *should* solve the menu issue.

Comment: @ERose: Is there a way to tell `main` to just autosize to the content called from `@RenderBody()`?

Comment: Not sure this is u looking but add this in #main - width:90%;    margin:5%; this make center justified the main.

Comment: Def still looking, thanks... this moved the content off the left side of the browser but by only about an inch. Still trying to get it centered.

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/prWB7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parent element to

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
#and some kind of height:
height: 350px;
```

The #page-div to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Ns/1/

Comment: THis really scrunches everything up and unfortunately still is left-justified. the `display:inline-block` though in the `.page` element does allow everything to autosize.

Comment: Also the `text-align:center` makes *everything* on the site (every page) centered.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but changing adding `display:table` and `margin: 0 auto` to the `.page` element worked. I actually no longer need the `contentContainer` div anymore. Here's the final product.

**CSS**

```
.page 
{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main 
{
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white; 
    /*border: 1px solid #999;*/
    border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
}
#content {
    padding: 20px;
}

footer, 
#footer 
{
    /*background-image: url('Images/TEST2body_bot.png');*/
    /*background-color: #fff;  */  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<body>
    @using Monet.Common
    <div class="page">  
        @Html.Partial("NavBarPartial")
        <section id="main">
            <div id="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>          
    <div id="footer">
        <span style="color: Gray;"></span>
    </div>           
</body>
```